# Using Google Maps api V3 with angular and browserify

Tags: angularjs, google-maps-api-3, browserify

I am trying to use the Google Maps Javascript Api V3 inside a Angular + browserify app.

I do not use bower.

Previously I was doing that with requirejs, and a plugins on git hub millermedeiros/requirejs-plugins called async.

I was able to load gmaps like this (most of the time, sometimes requirejs was still requireing gmaps too early.

```
 // load gmap as an amd module
 define(['config'], function(config){
     define('gmaps', ['async!http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=false&libraries=places&key=' + config['google-map-api-key']],
         function(){
             return window.google.maps;
         }
     );
 });
```

Browserify is kind of new, I don't see much documentation at this moment, do you guys have any recommendation ?

Answer (score 1):

To include CommonJS incompatible scripts have a look at Browserify-shim transform:

https://github.com/thlorenz/browserify-shim

Comment: I'll try this out, did you ?

Comment: Yes, i'm using it in one of my projects.

Comment: I am using browserify shim to shim some client library, but how to youimport gmap from an distant server asynchronously

Comment: You need to tell browserify-shim to treat it as a global dependency. Please have a look at this https://github.com/thlorenz/browserify-shim#a-expose-global-variables-via-global.